# Telerik radgridview, text overlaps WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, telerik, radgridview

it's a system for searching records.
when there's no records for a particular search,
a "no record found" will be shown.
there's no problem for the first time but when the second time onwards where there are no records found, another "no records found" will overlap the first one and all the previous ones.
what i want to achieve is to remove the "no records found" every time a new search is done and when there are records to be shown. i want that the "no records found" to only be initialised after an empty search is done.

what im using now is RadGridViewProperties.EmptyText

i cannot show any of the codes as it is company's property.

please help me to your best ability without seeing the code.

thank you.

Comment: Ya without showing us an example of your issue it's really hard to troubleshoot. However, you could possibly just swap your EmptyText thing you're doing with something like a TargetNullValue='no records found' or a FallbackValue='no records found' in your binding base instead.

Comment: May I know if there's any mistake in the code: RadGridViewProperties.cs in this page: http://www.telerik.com/forums/emptydatatemplate-radgridview

Comment: Actually, I'm a total noob when i comes to WPF and XAML. I just join this company as intern and was given this bug to solve. >.<